# Gstreamer pipeline causing stream to corrupt

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I have been trying to stream a live video from a RPi to a browser using GStreamer, i.e. RPi -> MediaServer -> Browser.

However the video that is display has become corrupted:
[Corrupted Video Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhPEe.png)

I have isolated the problem to the Gstreamer pipeline by streaming to a different port on the Pi and saving the stream to .mp4, however this video does not play.

### Bash Script to send Stream

```
PEER_A={KMS_AUDIO_PORT} PEER_V={KMS_VIDEO_PORT} PEER_IP={KMS_PUBLIC_IP} \
SELF_PATH="{PATH_TO_VIDEO_FILE}" \
SELF_A=5006 SELF_ASSRC=445566 \
SELF_V=5004 SELF_VSSRC=112233 \
bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes,cname=(string)\"user\@example.com\"" \
    rpicamsrc ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=150,framerate=25/1 ! decodebin name=d \
    d. ! x264enc tune=zerolatency \
        ! rtph264pay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=(int)103,clock-rate=(int)90000,ssrc=(uint)$SELF_VSSRC" \
        ! r.send_rtp_sink_1 \
    r.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink host=$PEER_IP port=$PEER_V bind-port=$SELF_V \
    r.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host=$PEER_IP port=$((PEER_V+1)) bind-port=$((SELF_V+1)) sync=false async=false \
    udpsrc port=$((SELF_V+1)) ! tee name=t \
        t. ! queue ! r.recv_rtcp_sink_1 \
        t. ! queue ! fakesink dump=true async=false'
```

### Script to Receive Stream and save to mp4

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=23938 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=~/Desktop/test.mp4
```

---

Any ideas on what is wrong about my pipeline setup would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Camera source resolution doesnt look proper. 200X150 is not a standard resolution. I am not sure whether this is the cause. But you can just check and confirm what is the camera output resolution once. Also you may have to specify color format (like format='(fourcc)'UYVY) of the camera.